# React 16 input type=checkbox not rendered correctly if nested in html a-tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a peculiar problem with using a html `a`-tag with `input type=checkbox`  from React. The thing is that if I click directly on the checkbox and not the `a`-tag the checkbox will not re-render correctly but my state has updated.

Example: Given the code below I render the component and click directly on the checkbox. In this case showMap will be set to false since we set it to true in the constructor but the checkbox will still be checked in the html view. If I however click on the `a`-tag but not directly on the checkbox both the state showMap is updated correctly as well as the view.

I can make it work by not calling `event.preventDefault();` in `toggleCheckbox` but if I do that the app will scroll to the top of the page if I click on the `a`-tag.

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w2x8vqq8xl

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center",
  //marginTop: "1000px"
};

class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMap: true
    };
  }

  toggleCheckbox = event => {
    this.setState({ showMap: !this.state.showMap });
    event.preventDefault();    
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.showMap ? "Show" : "hide"}</h1>
        <a href="#" role="button" onClick={this.toggleCheckbox}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            title="test"
            name="showMap"
            checked={this.state.showMap}
            readOnly
          />
          Show map
        </a>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
    <div style={styles}>
      <Menu />
    </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Update:**

Created an issue with React.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11539

Comment: It totally looks like a reactjs bug. If you report it please put a link in the question.

Comment: @zerkms I suspected that. Created issue and updated question with link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be browser native behavior:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" role="button" id="anchor">
  <input id="input" type="checkbox" title="test" name="showMap" readonly /> Clicking this text toggles the checkbox
</a>

<hr />
<label><input id="prevent" type="checkbox" /> Prevent Default</label>

<p>With prevent default on, clicking the checkbox does not toggle it. Only clicking the text</p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor')
var prevent = document.getElementById('prevent')
var input = document.getElementById('input')
var toggled = false

anchor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (prevent.checked) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  toggled = !toggled

  input.checked = toggled
})
```

https://codepen.io/nhunzaker/pen/WXONQK

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11539#issuecomment-343914330

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `#` in `href` you can use `javascript:void(0)` in your `a`-tag to avoid scroll to top. This is useful only if you are having scrolling issue when clicking `a` tag. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I wan't a solution for it and not a hack. :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `event.preventDefault()` use `event.stopPropagation()`

Read more about this at

https://medium.com/@jacobwarduk/how-to-correctly-use-preventdefault-stoppropagation-or-return-false-on-events-6c4e3f31aedb